# Indexes error while retrieving chat history from firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making ad posting platform using ReactJs and Firebase trying to retrieve chat history from "Chats" collection inside my firestore and I am getting the following error, I have added indexes as well but getting the same error again and again.

**Code:**

```js
const chatCollectionRef = collection(db, "Chats");
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
        query(
          chatCollectionRef,
          where("sender", "in", [senderId, receiverId]),
          where("receiver", "in", [senderId, receiverId]),
          where("timestamp", ">=", yesterdayTimestamp),
          where("timestamp", "<=", currentTimestamp),
          orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
        )
      );
```

**Error:**

> Error loading chat messages: FirebaseError: The query requires an index.

I tried to retrieve chat history between current logged in user and user who posted the ad.

Comment: Are you getting any link with error in debug console?

Comment: [Cloud Firestore ensures query performance by requiring an index for every query.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) You might want to review that documentation.

Comment: With error there is direct link to create index.

Comment: If you think you've added the required index for this query, edit your question to show a screenshot of that index.